azure create wiki page
I tried this command
az devops wiki page create --path 'my page' --wiki myprojectwiki --content "Hello World"    

from ms docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cli/azure/devops/wiki/page?view=azure-cli-latest
and I'm getting this error

ERROR: cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: unrecognized arguments: page'
ERROR: az_command_data_logger: unrecognized arguments: page'

I'm running it from DevOps pipeline.

you can check the sample pipeline below with Microsoft-hosted agent for a check, it works on my side. If you use self-hosted agent, please try to reinstall Azure CLI and DevOps extension. Let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

Try below code in your DevOps pipeline:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- bash: az devops wiki page create --path 'my page' --wiki wadetest6.wiki --content "Hello World" 
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(pat)

$(pat): is the personal access token, you can simply create a full scope token.
If you don't have a wiki yet, please create it firstly.

You can get the wiki name from browser url, typically it's projectname.wiki. If you have already wiki, use the existing wiki name.

If you are using self-hosted agent, reinstall azure cli, and add devops extension az extension add --name azure-devops(doc here), then restart the agent, then rerun the pipeline for a check.

I was able to create a sample Wiki page using the following command:
az devops wiki page create \
  --path '/my page' \
  --wiki 'myproject.wiki' \
  --content 'Hello world' \
  --project 'myproject'

Notes:

default wiki is {project-name}.wiki
--path is the path of the wiki page starting with a / - example: /myfolder/mysubfolder/wikipage

I'm using Azure CLI v2.61.0 and Azure DevOps CLI v1.0.1
